# 'wp_login' action hook not working with wp-login.php file

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin, hooks, actions

Wordpress 4.9.5

I am work on demo to check after login call some action or function, so that i prepare one plugin. Here is the code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test Login
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/plugins/
Description: This is not just a plugin,
Version: 1.0
*/


function your_function() {
    echo "123";
    echo "<script>alert('login')</script>";
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function');
```

But it is not working after successful login from this URL : http://localhost/test_wordpress/wp-login.php.
It will redirect to dashboard and alert message was not display.
Please help for that.

Thank you.

Comment: Any idea from [this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164107/discussion-between-alex-vand-and-gabed123)?

Comment: No i didn't get any idea from that @MayeenulIslam

Answer (score 3):

[`wp_login`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/) is fired in `wp_signon` after the user has successfully logged in.

That's after submitting the login form, so obviously you can't execute any JavaScript there. Of course you can still do something in PHP.

If you want to execute JavaScript after login, you need to find another hook.

Comment: Thank you, Which hook execute after successfully login except 'wp_login'

Comment: If you want to execute PHP after logging in, `wp_login` is fine. If you want to execute JavaScript in the admin area after logging in, you could look at the `admin_head` hook for example.